# What happens when you don't do a hclose after a hopen in KDB+

Tags: kdb

What happens when you don't close a hopen handle with a hclose?

```
h:hopen `:mydb.us.com:5010
```

Will the connection pool eventually run out or will KDB automatically close those that are inactive after awhile?

Regards,

Just Beginning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The connection pool will eventually run out. You can have a maximum of 1022 open connection handles (incoming and outgoing).

There is a max of 8192 open file handles too.

Comment: `count .z.W` will return the number of currently open ipc handles. See [here](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/dotzdotW) for more details on `.z.W`

Comment: For environments with multiple users and you don't really know who opened an IPC handle, it there an option to flush it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'flush it' ? You can close both outgoing and incoming handles with [`hclose`](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/hclose) - moreover, you can track which user + ip address an incoming connection is associated with by logging [`.z.u`](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/dotzdotu) and [`.z.a`](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/dotzdota) to a table / log file within the [`.z.po`](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/dotzdotpo) (port open) event handler

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @MdSalih

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea but i'm doing this now
`hclose each (key .z.W)`